# SDL library undefined symbols for main()

Tags: c++, macos, sdl, undefined-reference

I implemented a Tetris game from an old tutorial that uses SDL v1.2.15. However, I cannot compile the code because main() seems undefined.

I first copy the include and lib folders under SDL directory to my current directory

```
project
    -- include
    -- lib
    -- Makefile
    -- main.cpp
```

Then I import the headers:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>                                    
#include <SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h>
```

When I came to main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

I also tried:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

and

```
int main()
```

But I get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)
```

I use the Makefile commands to compile the code:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS= -c -I include
LDFLAGS= -I include -L lib -lSDL -lSDL_gfx
SOURCES= main.cpp game.cpp board.cpp io.cpp pieces.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=tetris

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I am currently using `macOS Catalina` and `VSCode`

How can I avoid this error, and SDL2 does not help because some functions are defined only in SDL.

Comment: Even if the tutorial uses SDL 1, perhaps you're linking with version 2 (the mention of `SDL_main` is an indicator)? Since SDL version 2 it provides its own `main` function, which in turn invokes `SDL_main` which should be your new main entry point. It should all be in the documentation as well as plenty of tutorials.

Comment: With that said, I think it's possible to change it so you provide the `main` function, but you have to define some preprocessor macro (IIRC).

Comment: Are you sure the headers in `-I include` are for SDL1.2 rather than SDL2?